# How to code/reference to a PHP callable functions easy to manage for my IDE

Tags: php, ide, closures, anonymous-function, callable

When I have to write a reference to a callable function I use the standard syntax of PHP [defined as](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.callable.php):

> A PHP function is **passed by its name as a string**. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used *[... omitted...]*.
>
> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the **method name** *(aka string)*
>   at index 1.
>
> Static class methods can also be passed without instantiating an object of that class by passing the **class name**  *(still a string)*
>   instead of an object at index 0.
>
> As of PHP 5.2.3, it is also possible to pass  *(the string)*  **'ClassName::methodName'**.
>
> Apart from common user-defined function, anonymous functions can also be passed to a callback parameter.

All of these ways are not "IDE friendly" for operations like *function name refactor* or *find usage of*.

In my answer I propose a solution, but there are other approaches that can be applied, even totally different, that allow to IDE to "find" the invocation of the methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already are next to the shortest thing you can do

You can perfectly call your anonymous function directly in your function call without using a variable

For instance, you can replace:

```
$callable=function($param) use ($object){ 
   return $object->myMethod($param); 
}
call_user_func($callable, $param);
```

by:

```
call_user_func(function($param) use ($object){ 
   return $object->myMethod($param); 
}, $param);
```

You will have to wait for [arrow functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions) in future PHP versions, and you should be able to use something like:

```
call_user_func(fn($a) => $object->myMethod($a), $param);
```

Answer (score 2):

I became to a solution, always based on the [anonymous-functions](http://php.net/manual/it/functions.anonymous.php) that solve the problem but leave me not full satisfied:

**Static method of a class**

```
$callable = function($param){ 
    return \my\namespace\myClass::myMethod($param); 
}
```

**method of a object**

```
$callable = function($param) use ($object){ 
    return $object->myMethod($param); 
}
```

**method of $this object**

```
$callable = function($param){ 
    return self::myMethod($param); 
}
```

---

**Alternatives for oldest php versions**

Inside the all classess you gonna call (or in their parents) define the function *classname()* as follow:

```
public static function className()
{
    return get_called_class();
}
```

or for *very* old PHP:

```
public static function className()
{
    return "MyClass";
}
```

Then

```
call_user_func(array(MyClass::className(), 'myCallbackMethod'));
```